# spinner value doesn't change by setselected

Tags: android, android-spinner

I am trying to set the value to spinner by setselected(pos) it is working for some of the spinner but not for all. this is my code where i am trying to set the values.

```
  ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapterItem = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.Item, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapterItem.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        edmORdelOF.setAdapter(adapterItem);
        System.out.println(profile.getEdmORdelOF()+"....getPosition..........."+adapterItem.getPosition(profile.getEdmORdelOF()));
        edmORdelOF.setSelection(adapterItem.getPosition(profile.getEdmORdelOF()));


        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.Org_type, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        org_type.setAdapter(adapter);
        System.out.println(profile.getD_org_type()+"....getPosition..........."+adapter.getPosition(profile.getD_org_type()));
        org_type.setSelection(adapter.getPosition(profile.getD_org_type()));



        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapterCountry = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.Country, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapterCountry.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        country.setAdapter(adapterCountry);
        System.out.println(profile.getD_country()+"....getPosition..........."+adapterCountry.getPosition(profile.getD_country()));
        country.setSelection(adapterCountry.getPosition(profile.getD_country()));



    // this part doesn't work properly.
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adpState = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.India_States, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adpState.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        state.setAdapter(adpState);

        System.out.println(profile.getD_state()+"....getPosition..........."+adpState.getPosition(profile.getD_state()));

        state.setSelection(adpState.getPosition(profile.getD_state()));


        if(state.getSelectedItem().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Maharashtra"))
        {
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapterCity = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.Maharashtra_city, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapterCity.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        District.setAdapter(adapterCity);
        System.out.println(profile.getD_city()+"....getPosition..........."+adapterCity.getPosition(profile.getD_city()));
        District.setSelection(adapterCity.getPosition(profile.getD_city()));
        }
        else if(state.getSelectedItem().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("karnataka"))
        {
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapterCity = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.Karnataka_District, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapterCity.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        District.setAdapter(adapterCity);
        System.out.println(profile.getD_city()+"....getPosition..........."+adapterCity.getPosition(profile.getD_city()));
        District.setSelection(adapterCity.getPosition(profile.getD_city()));
        }
        else if(state.getSelectedItem().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Goa"))
        {
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapterCity = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.goa_District, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapterCity.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        District.setAdapter(adapterCity);
        System.out.println(profile.getD_city()+"....getPosition..........."+adapterCity.getPosition(profile.getD_city()));
        District.setSelection(adapterCity.getPosition(profile.getD_city()));
        }

        taluka = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.Updatesp_sign_up_taluka);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adaptertaluka = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.Ratnagiri_taluka, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adaptertaluka.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        taluka.setAdapter(adaptertaluka);
        adaptertaluka.notifyDataSetChanged();
        System.out.println(profile.getD_district()+"....getPosition..........."+adaptertaluka.getPosition(profile.getD_district()));
        taluka.setSelection(adaptertaluka.getPosition(profile.getD_district()));
```

in this code it is working fine for all the spinner except he state. plz help me out. i am not getting any thing how to solve this problem.

Comment: Must be sure that did you get right value using this **state.getSelectedItem().toString()** while comparing?

Comment: What value are you getting here - System.out.println(profile.getD_state()+"....getPosition..........."+adpState.getPosition(profile.getD_state())); and did you try hard coding it just to check?

Comment: hi atul. i get the proper value i.e the positon and the name of the state.